# apex_item.checkbox2 behavior when naming parameters

Tags: oracle, checkbox, plsql, oracle-apex

This query returns the checkbox html I would expect in the SQL Commands window of Oracle apex:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,empno,DECODE(deptno,10,'CHECKED',NULL)) "Select", ename, job
FROM emp
WHERE deptno = 10

i.e. <input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="7782" CHECKED />
```

But if I explicitly name my parameters, I don't get the correct result:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(p_idx=>1,p_value=>empno,p_checked_values=>DECODE(deptno,10, 'CHECKED',NULL)) "Select", ename, job
FROM emp
WHERE deptno = 10

<input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="7782" />
```

I don't understand why naming the parameters in accordance with the documentation would cause this issue. This is from the online doc:

```
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(
p_idx                       IN    NUMBER,
p_value                     IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_attributes                IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_checked_values            IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_checked_values_delimiter  IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ':',
p_item_id                   IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_item_label                IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the only difference "CHECKED"?

You're using `p_checked_values` wrong:

[From Apex Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI193) :

`p_checked_values` : Values to be checked by default

Basically, when using `p_checked_values`, you pass in a list of delimited values for which the `'CHECKED'` indicator will be used where `p_value` in the list `p_checked_values` (delimited by the parameter `p_checked_values_delimiter`). The reason it worked before is you were passing this as the third parameter, which is actually `p_attributes` which just go into the generated HTML tag directly without parsing or alteration. To fix your code use the below since the `'CHECKED'` attribute is not determined by the value being passed to `p_value`:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(p_idx=>1,p_value=>empno,p_attributes=>DECODE(deptno,10, 'CHECKED',NULL)) "Select", ename, job
FROM emp
WHERE deptno = 10
```

Comment: Brilliant! I knew I had to be missing something obvious but I don't think I would have figured that out. Thank you for taking the time to help and for the thorough explanation!